# Apollo Server 3 Express middleware not working with React SSR Routing

Tags: express, react-apollo, apollo-server

I recently upgrade from `apollo-server-express:2.25.4` to `:3.9.0`

I didn't need many migrations, however initially any request to `/graphql` were answered not by the apollo server middleware, but instead by the React SSR middleware I also used (`@apollo/client/react/ssr:3.6.8`).

I had to manually add the following lines to my SSR middleware in order for the requests to go through:

```
+ if (req.url == "/graphql") {
+   return next();
+ }

const client = new ApolloClient(...);

renderToStringWithData(...)
    .then((content) => {
        const state = client.extract();
        const html = <Html content={content} state={JSON.stringify(state)} />;
        res.send(`<!doctype html>\n${ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(html)}`);
    })
    .catch(...);
```

Now, this works; however I want to know why it was necessary? I combed through the changelogs but wasn't able to find any change in `apollo-server-express` as to why I need to add this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the change to an async method for starting the apollo server was to blame.

In Apollo 3 you need to first call `start()` and then apply the actual middleware:

```
// app: ExpressApplication
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer(...);
apolloServer.start().then(() => server.applyMiddleware({ app }));
```

As this is an asynchronous method, the SSR middleware I applied was actually ordered *before* the Apollo middleware

```
createApolloServer(app); // see above
app.use(renderDom); // see question
```

And as such the SSR was executed before the Apollo Server, requiring me to add the if-clause to prevent the `/graphql` route being rendered by SSR.

Another fix of course is to properly wait for the async function and then apply the SSR middleware afterwards:

```
createApolloServer(app).then(() => {
    app.use(renderDom);
    app.listen(...);
});
```